# Can we transform a graph in a way that applying DFS to the new graph would result in the same traversal order as applying BFS on the first graph?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, category-theory

This question is *purely theoretical.*

Let's say you have a **graph A**, a **Depth-First Search algorithm** and a **Breadth-First Search** that both searches a graph for nodes matching a given predicate and returning the list of matching nodes in the **order** they have been encountered during the graph traversal.

My question is :

Does there exists a **graph B** such that applying the **DFS algorithm** to it would give you the *same result* as if we applied a **Breadth-First Search algorithm** to **graph A** ?

IE The list of matching nodes returned by the BFS algorithm on graph A is the same list of nodes (same nodes in the **same order**) returned by the DFS algorithm applied to graph B.

And if so, what algorithm is able to transform graph A into graph B ?

If such graph B does not exists in general, for any graph A, does one exists if we put restrictions on which graph A are allowed ? (such as no cycles for example, ie being a tree)

PS: The problem formulated like this make me think of the illustration of functors, thus the category-theory tag.

**EDIT:**
Now that I have seen that a trivial solution to my question exists, I realize that my actual question is rather in the specific case of **infinite graphs**. I thought that asking if there was a solution *in general* would cover it, but that was before I saw the linked-list solution which seems to be only applicable on **finite graphs**.

Comment: Unfortunately, the answer isn't just "yes, there is".  It's "of course there is".

Comment: I have a graph.  Its BFS ordering of nodes v1, v2, .... vn.  Constructing a graph that has v1, v2, ... v2 as its depth-first ordering is trivial.  Is there something more to this problem?

Comment: @Frank Yellin I would have thought that the solution would not be a linked list but something looking more like a tree. This has made me realize that the question I want to ask is in fact in the specific case of infinite graphs. And although theoretical, it originated from my attempts to program under constraints (just a learning toy) something that fits the problem I specified, which main goal is precisely to inquire what is possible and what isn't.

Comment: @Frank Yellin I also thought (wrongly), that it was another instance of a real problem with real applications this time. The problem is : given a data structure (dsc) A which serves as input of an algorithm A. You decide to use an arbitrary algorithm C to transform dsc A into dsc B. The only constrainst of C is that it should be reversible (ie information is preserved). Can you produce an algorithm B, in function of dsc A, algo A, and algo C, such that applying algo B on dsc B produce the same results as applying algo A on dsc A ?

Comment: @Frank Yellin I ask myself this question when confronted with a lopsided trie that I wanted to equilibrate "manually". I hope that a solution to this problem would give us a method to write mechanically a different version of an existing algorithm with different complexity characteristics, ie a different tims VS memory tradeoff. And the use case of this, if possible, would be in optimizing compilers, to execute a piece of a program with the best compexity characteristics to maximize globally the overall program execution.

Answer (score 1):

Let's leave **A** out of this, since the only thing which is interesting is the sequence of nodes in the breadth-first traverse of **A**: *v*<sub>1</sub>, *v*<sub>2</sub>, *v*<sub>3</sub>, …, *v*<sub>n</sub>.

Then the question is, can we create a graph whose depth-first traverse must be exactly the sequence *v*<sub>1</sub>, *v*<sub>2</sub>, *v*<sub>3</sub>, …, *v*<sub>n</sub>? And clearly we can: the nodes of the graph are {*v*<sub>1</sub>, *v*<sub>2</sub>, *v*<sub>3</sub>, …, *v*<sub>n</sub>} and its edges are {< *v*<sub>i</sub>, *v*<sub>i+1</sub>> for *i* ∈ {1, …, *n*−1} } (It's breadth-first traverse is the same.)

Another trivial algorithm is to take any graph **B'** with *n* nodes, and do a depth-first traverse on it. Say the result is the sequence  *u*<sub>1</sub>, *u*<sub>2</sub>, *u*<sub>3</sub>, …, *u*<sub>n</sub>. Then construct the graph **B** from **B'** by renaming every  *u*<sub>i</sub> as *v*<sub>i</sub>, which will have the effect of changing the breadth-first traverse to match the breadth-first traverse of **A**.

Comment: This is not really what I was looking for but this works and shows to me that I hadn't thought this through. I guess we could transform this linked list into a more equilibrated binary tree so that the DFS isn't reduce to simply iterating over the a linear list.

Comment: @WhiteMist: The second example, which just renames all the nodes, applies to any shaped graph. So you can't get out of the problem just be restricting the shapes. I understand that you're looking for some relationship (or non-relationship) between depth-first and breadth-first traverses, but I think node labels are a dead end.

Comment: Also, I don't think there is an obvious impediment to using the node-renaming algorithm to produce **B**, even if **A** is infinite. Although it's possible that there is some unstated property of node labels in an infinite graph which would make that non-trivial.